# Display gif on button click and hide after function finish in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How can i show a gif after buttonclick and hide it when a function is finished?

```
<ISWebDesktop:WebButton ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="20px" Text="Ablehnen" meta:resourcekey="btnAblehnen" Width="75px"
                        AutoPostback="True" PostBackMode="FullPostBack">                    
                    </ISWebDesktop:WebButton>

 <asp:Image ID="emailLoader2" runat="server" ImageUrl="../../images/ajax-loader2.gif" Visible="false"/>
```

Codebehind:

```
Protected Sub Button3_Clicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ISNet.WebUI.WebDesktop.WebButtonClickedEventArgs) Handles Button3.Clicked
    //show the gif
    Dim msg As String = "OK"
    Dim spezial As Integer = 0
    .....
    //hides the gif
    END SUB
```

Comment: for this kind of operation you need to use client side scription not serverside scripting

Comment: can you give me an example please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use jquery to get data asynchronously. Assuming your current page is `index.html`, which contains:

```
<p style="display: none;"><img src="loading.gif" />Loading...</p>
```

It's a hidden loading bar. Then, use jquery `.post` or `.get` method to get data from your another page like:

```
$.get("test.asp", function () {
    $("img").delay(500).hide();
    $("p").text("Loading Complete.");
});
```

So here's the final calling order:

1. Click button in `index.html`
2. Shows loading bar
3. Jquery calls `.get()` function to execute `test.asp`
4. After `test.asp` execution finished, hide the loading gif, change the loading text.